# Filtering / sorting of Managed Metadata Columns not working

Tags: 2013, list, metadata, filter

We're experiencing some issues with Managed Metadata columns in a list view.
- filtering is not working
- sort order seems to be wrong

Sorting:

[image: Listview]

The sort order seems to follow the term ID, not the term label.

Filtering:
In this case I try to filter the column "Ticket Priority" for "**1 Critical**" - no results are visible.

If we take a look to the URL it shows:
`https://server.domain.net/site/Lists/test/AllItems.aspx#InplviewHashf16b49bc-05a1-4302-a6e0-aec9fba58b0f=`**SortField%3DTicketPriority-SortDir%3DDesc-FilterField1%3DTicketPriority-FilterValue1%3D3-FilterOp1%3DIn-FilterLookupId1%3D1-FilterData1%3D0%252C3c094313%252Dae66%252D4df7%252Db82b%252D314d74fcdf86**

--> The term "1 Critical" has the ID 3c094313-ae66-4df7-b82b-314d74fcdf86

If I manually modify the bold part of the URL as follows:
`https://server.domain.net/site/Lists/test/AllItems.aspx#InplviewHashf16b49bc-05a1-4302-a6e0-aec9fba58b0f=`**CascDelWarnMessage%3D1-SortField%3DTicketPriority-SortDir%3DDesc-FilterField1%3DTicketPriority-FilterValue1%3D1%20Critical**

--> I get the filtered view I want!

As I understand, the filtering / sorting is happening to the term ID.

Does anybody have an idea how to get it work?

### **Update**

I found some more Infos in this german TechNet Forum
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/9be3fb1d-13c9-4d33-b833-19e17ba36150/metadatennavigation-funktioniert-nicht-in-aufgabenlisten-sharepoint-2013?forum=Sharepointde

### It seems to be an unfixed bug, this issue occurs on Task lists with Managed Metadata columns. It also seems that no fix is available right now.

regards, Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround for us is a dummy-column (filled by a workflow) which is used for filtering.

BR, Alex